# Add as an library to main project

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

Basically I want to add one of my project as an library to my main project.
Because my main project refer some classes of other project.
But as normal way I can't able to do that. So I am giving here details regarding that.

My motto is to use classes of other project. That's it.

[image]

Here in image, **BaseGameUtils** is my library project and **Smove-android** is my main game project.

But when I try to add it into actual project, I can't able to see in library section.

[image]

Now please give me some suggestion in this. I want to use classes of library project.

**EDIT :** Library project build.gradle file.

[image]

Comment: Show us your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: `BaseGameProject` is a `gradle` style project and you are trying to import in `eclipse` style project

Comment: I have added build.gradle file of library project.

Comment: main game project gradle file link : http://pastebin.com/9Cms9DBz

Comment: you need to mark your project as library project.

Answer (score 0):

right click the library you want to add->properties->
under "Android" section check "Is Library" checkbox.
apply and save.
then follow how you normally add a library project to your app.

Comment: Please check following image link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqtyopt2kcb6yi2/properties%20of%20base%20game%20utils.png?dl=0

Comment: its not an android project

Comment: Thanks for your project. Any how I want to resolve this problem. What I need to do? I want to use reference project as my library because my main project uses those projects classes. I think I need to create a dummy android project and paste all details of reference project into this dummy project. what do you think about this?

Comment: No, it is not work for me. I am trying to integrate this BaseGameUtils into my project. https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples